# Proving that $L = \left\{a^{n^2} | n \ge 0\right\}$ is not context free with Pumping Lemma for CFG?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

> $$L = \left\{\left. a^{n^2} \right| n \ge 0\right\}$$

I don't quite understand this problem.

Comment: How do you generally use the Pumping Lemma to prove the language is not context-free?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. You could use the result that, on a one-letter alphabet, a context-free language is regular. Consequently, it suffices to prove that your language is not regular, and thus the pumping lemma for regular languages suffices to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy actually! The definition of Pumping Lema is if a language is a context-free language for all strings $S\in L$ with $|S|\ge n$ ,there exists $u, v, w, x, y ∈ Σ∗,$ such that $S = uvwxy$ with:

1- $|vwx| \le n$

2- $|vx| \ge 1$

3- for all $i \ge 0$, $uv^iwx^iy \in L$

What it says in a nutshell is that in any context-free the language you can break it into five parts and pump(add) more symbols in some parts and will still generate a string that belongs to language. we need to contradict that fact to prove it's not a context-free language

Let's start by seeing the structure of the language:
$L = \{λ,a,aaaa,aaaaaaaaa,...\}$
this language is so simple, it just contains the symbol $a$ so it's obvious that the middle part $|vwx|$ would contain the symbol $a$(notice it repeat by a complete square number).

we will assume that it's a context-free language that means all the rules applies. 
Since 
(1) tells us that $vwx$ could contain $a$  and (2) tells us that $vx$ contains at least one $a$ which means that $vwx$ must contain at least 1 $a$.

Now let's check (3): based on (1) and (2) $|uwy| \le n^2-1$ which means that the maximum length of $uwy$ is $n^2-1$, since $uv^iwx^iy \in L$ when i=0 then $uwy \in L$ which is not always true because if $n^2$ is a complete square that doesn't mean $n^2-1$ is also a complete square thus makes a contradiction.